# Ruby .ceil and .floor

Tags: ruby, math, floor, ceil

I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to figure out how `ceil` and `floor` works as I get different answers when a fraction or a decimal number is used (similar value). Below is what I have tried:

```
puts 8/3.ceil == 2   #=> true
puts 8/3.floor == 2  #=> true
puts 2.67.ceil == 2  #=> false
puts 2.67.floor == 2 #=> true
```

From my understanding, `ceil` should return a number higher and `floor` is a number lower. Hope someone can enlighten me on this. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Everything is returned correctly.

```
puts 8/3.ceil == 2
#=> true, because 8/3 returns an Integer, 2
puts 8/3.floor == 2
#=> true, because 8/3 returns an Integer, 2
puts 2.67.ceil == 2
#=> false, because 2.67.ceil is 3
puts 2.67.floor == 2
#=> true, because 2.67.floor is 2
```

To make things of more sense here, you can convert results to Float:

```
(8.to_f / 3).ceil == 2  #=> false
(8.to_f / 3).floor == 2 #=> true
2.67.ceil == 2          #=> false
2.67.floor == 2         #=> true
```

Another thing to bear in mind, that having written `8/3.ceil` is actually `8 / (3.ceil)`, because the `.` binds stronger than `/`. (thx **@tadman**)

Yet another thing to mention, is that (thx **@Stefan**):

> There's also [`fdiv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-fdiv) to perform floating point division, i.e.
>   `8.fdiv(3).ceil`. And Ruby also comes with a nice [`Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Rational.html) class: `(8/3r).ceil`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning `8/3.floor` is actually `8/(3.floor)` since the `.` binds stronger than `/`.

Comment: Ahh alright! So for the first line, it's actually doing 3.ceil first, resulting in 3, and then an integer division of 8/3, which is why it's 2 (true) instead of 3 (false) like the 3rd line. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @misokuan  `it's actually doing 3.ceil first, resulting in 3, and then an integer division of 8/3, which is why it's 2` yes, that's correct.

Comment: There's also [`fdiv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-fdiv) to perform floating point division, i.e. `8.fdiv(3).ceil`. And Ruby also comes with a nice [`Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html) class: `(8/3r).ceil`

Comment: https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence
Precedence rules always tell the tale of mysterious calculations. :)